# Zend Acl in Service Layer/Navigation

Tags: zend-framework, acl

Im working on a "what I thought would be simple" application using zend framework.  This is my 4th application with zf, but my first with a dynamic ACL.  Application uses standard MVC setup with Model/Domain Layer consisting of a Service Layer to access my Models(popo) which are mapped through Mappers.  For each Model I have a corresponding Service and Mapper.  I would like to have my UserModel implement the Role interface and then all my model based services implement the Resource interface.  Also I would like to have specified predefined privileges based on static roles, but also be able to change specified privileges for each user based on the user's role(s);

So for instance:
I role of 'vendor' that by default has access to the 'invoice' resource with 'create', 'edit' and 'view' privileges.
So my InvoiceService I would would be the 'invoice' resource with methods create, edit, view, and delete(but by default only role admin could delete an invoice.

For a specific user with role of vendor I would like to be able to grant delete privilege, or for another user with vendor role I might like to be able to deny edit privilege.  This im thinking would have to be persisted in some way and dynamically loaded.

So to my actual question(s).
Am I going about this the wrong way?
Also how could a solution like this be implemented with Zend Navigation?

Any ideas pointers lessons feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if I have done a crap job with my explanation been up all night.

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea regarding roles, resources, and privileges. One question: When you asked how to do this with `Zend_Navigation`, did you mean with `Zend_Acl`? Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925970/zend-acl-how-to-design-role-based-acl-for-multiple-small-teams/5926152#5926152) for some ideas about `Zend_Acl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as David said you are on the right track.  Zend_Navigation plays very nicely with Zend_Acl.  You can define your navigation in an xml or ini file, assigning each page a resource and required privilege, and then inject the ACL and the navigation container into the navigation view helper.  You can also set the current role for the navigation helper to whomever is currently logged in, which will show or hide navigation elements based on the ACL.

I will say that defining all those pages in a navigation container is a bit tedious and verbose, but not difficult.

As for defining your ACL, you can do something as simple as defining all your roles and resources in a single php file, or you can have a more flexible approach and store this information in a database and build the acl.  You'd definitely want to cache the ACL with the latter approach.